# [ng update]: Error - The "@angular-devkit/schematics" package cannot be resolved from the workspace root directory

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
ng update
```

> The "@angular-devkit/schematics" package cannot be resolved from the
>   workspace root directory. This may be due to an unsupported node
>   modules structure. Please remove both the "node_modules" directory and
>   the package lock file; and then reinstall. If this does not correct
>   the problem, please temporarily install the
>   "@angular-devkit/schematics" package within the workspace. It can be
>   removed once the update is complete.

Comment: If you search for `@angular-devkit/schematics` using your IDE does it exist anywhere other than package-lock.json?

Comment: @AndrewAllen No I haven't found it.

Answer (score 78):

I had this issue

First I ran this to see the structure of the package

> npm ls @angular-devkit/schematics

it returned....

> Mms@0.0.0 C:\Users\wgrant\source\repos\WD\MMS\Mms\ClientApp
>
> `-- (empty)

since it was empty I ran the following (if yours is not empty maybe try update instead of install)

> npm install @angular-devkit/schematics

and after this, the 'ng update' ran successfuly

Answer (score 37):

first use the command

```
npm remove -g @angular/cli
```

and then

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

in my case solved and installed the latest version of the angular

Comment: I am trying to go from angular 11 to 12 to 13 and getting stuck on the 11 to 12 step. Other libraries are complaining ..

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I needed to just run

```
npm install
```

then the command

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

completed successfully

Answer (score 9):

npm install @angular-devkit/schematics

solved the problem for me

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was running the `ng update` command in a directory which didn't have the `package.json`. Running the command in correct directory fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update
```

and

```
npm install
```

fixed this issue for me just now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just Create New Project by using **ng new prjName**.
2. Check for @angular-devkit/schematics if not found then run **npm install @angular-devkit/schematics**
3. It will install @angular-devkit/schematics if finds any vulnerability just fix them by **npm audit fix**
4. Just hit **ng update @angular/cli@^10 @angular/core@^10** for specific version (here for version 10) or just run **ng update**
5. npm cache clean --force
6. ng update